# Router with arduino

Tags: communication, wireless

Is it possible to send and receive data from a normal router using arduino? I need to create a little device that uses a router to communicate with a remote. It's a close circuit.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a network interface (wired or wireless), yes, of course it is.

Look into the ESP8266, and ESP-12E-based boards such as the Adafruit Huzzah; they can be programmed in an Arduino environment, and have built-in wifi.

Comment: I need a normal router. Like the one you would you at home but a lot more powerful.

Comment: How powerful your router is is irrelevant. The problem is connecting to the Arduino. The standard boards don't have a network interface; you need an ethernet or wireless shield for that, but there are arduino-compatible boards, usually based on the ESP8266, that have built-in wifi.

Comment: So I can do it, directly or not!

Answer (score -1):

Yes ,You CAN.
Use ESP 8266-07.Its a very good Wi-Fi module.You juts need to install ESP8266 board file in Arduno IDE.
For board file installation and some basic tutorial , just
[Click here](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/esp8266-thing-hookup-guide/installing-the-esp8266-arduino-addon)

Its helpful I think.